# In h2o tool I get sql exception error when tries to import table from database

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, h2o

In my Build path it is mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre10.jar driver. When I try to import sql table in H2o , getting SQL Exception error below is the image:

[image]

Comment: please post the version of h2o you are using. please also review the documentation on providing and setting up a jdbc driver here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html?#jdbc-databases

Comment: @lauren, version of h2o is 3.20.0.5. I go through the document and found a class path to start i.e java -cp <path_to_h2o_jar>:<path_to_jdbc_driver_jar> water.H2OApp. I have execute the above code in git bash but got an error as "Error: Could not find or load main class DriverMicrosoft
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DriverMicrosoft
"

Comment: can you verify that your class path is set correctly? I just seems like your error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DriverMicrosoft` indicates that your classpath is not set correctly.